# What are the requirements to have an acheivement pop?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

I'm wondering, in Overwatch, are there some parameters that makes you unable to get achievements?

I know that in some games, You can't earn achievements in private games.

To know where I can and can not get achievements would be helpful to farm hard achievements like 'The path is closed' and 'The floor is lava'.

To recap, can you get achievement in:

- Private Friend only games
- The practice range
- VS AI
- etc.

Comment: This is answered in the very text of every achievement I can think of.

Comment: Yeah was at work when that question popped into my mind. And now that I think about it, yes, they say it in the description of pretty much every acheivement. I am dumb.

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. Maybe "which game modes allow you to earn achievements?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the description of almost any achievement:

> "[insert task here] in **quick** or **competitive** play"

So no, achievements can only be earned if you are playing in quick or competitive. Since you don't get XP in Private games, you can't get the player level achievements that way but you can get them if you play vs.AI, which would take a lot more time than playing in Quick or Competitive.

Comment: Worth also mentioning you can get XP, and thus level achievements, in the weekly brawl too.

Comment: Oh they updated the achievements to include competitive play?

Comment: Most achievements also do not work in arcade mode